# How does $(n+1)^2 + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ equal $\frac{(n+1)(n(2n+1)+6(n+1))}{6}$?

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I have a basic question regarding induction.

We want to prove this by induction:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

The solution looks like this:

Prove $A(n+1): \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 = (n+1)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \\= (n+1)^2 + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\ = \frac{(n+1)(n(2n+1)+6(n+1))}{6}\\ = \frac{(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)}{6} \\ = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$$

Sory if this is a stupid question, but how do we get to $\frac{(n+1)(n(2n+1)+6(n+1))}{6}$ ?

Comment: Just do it:  $(n+1)^2 + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac {6(n+1)^2}{6} +  \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} =\frac {6(n+1)^2 +n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$ so we just factor out the $n+1$.  $\frac {6\color{green}{(n+1)}^2 +n\color{green}{(n+1)}(2n+1)}6 = \frac{\color{green}{(n+1)}[6(n+1) + n(2n+1)}6$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite $(n+1)^2$ as $6(n+1)^2/6$, add the two fractions with the common denominator $6$, and factor out $(n+1)/6$.

Answer (score 3):

Second step of induction

$A(n+1)$:Add $(n+1)^2$ to the both sides, since formula for the terms is $k^2$

And by factorizing

$2n^2+7n+6=(2n+3)(n+2)$

$$(n+1)^2 + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\ = \frac{6(n+1)^2+n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}= \frac{(n+1)(n(2n+1)+6(n+1))}{6}\\ = \frac{(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)}{6} \\ = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually trying to prove is that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n}} k^2 = \frac{\color{red}{[n]}(\color{red}{[n]} + 1)(2\color{red}{[n]} + 1)}{6}. \tag1 $$

The idea behind induction is that you start with (1) above as a premise, and then prove that the formula applies when $\color{red}{[n]}$ is replaced by $\color{red}{[n + 1]}.$

So, with (1) above as a premise, your goal is to prove:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n+1}} k^2 = \frac{\color{red}{[n+1]}(\color{red}{[n+1]} + 1)(2\color{red}{[n+1]} + 1)}{6}. \tag2 $$

---

So, the problem reduces to showing that :

the RHS of (1) above $~+~ (n+1)^2 = ~$ the RHS of (2) above.